# How to input ip address from keyboard in Go?

Tags: go

Im trying to input IP address from keyboard in Go. When Im trying to input IP address using bufio i can`t convert "*bufio.Convert" type to "string" type. When Im trying to input ip address using Scanf() program skips input of second variable. What I must to do if i want to convert input to string?

```
import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "net"
    "os"
)

func checkerror(err error) {
   if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error:=", err)
   }
}

func main() {
   typeofoperation := bufio.NewScanner(os.Stdin)
   typeofoperation.Scan()
   typeofoperation.Text()
   //fmt.Println("IP or TCP dial?")
   //fmt.Println("Input Address")
   //fmt.Scanf("%s", &typeofoperation)
   //fmt.Scanf("%s", &addr)
   addr := bufio.NewScanner(os.Stdin)
   addr.Scan()
   addr.Text()
      if typeofoperation == "tcp" {
         address, err := net.ResolveTCPAddr("tcp", addr)
         checkerror(err)
         conn, err1 := net.DialTCP("tcp", nil, address)
         checkerror(err1)
         fmt.Println(conn, "TCP end")
      } else if typeofoperation == "ip" {
         address, err := net.ResolveIPAddr("ip", addr)
         checkerror(err)
         conn, err1 := net.DialIP("ip", nil, address)
         checkerror(err1)
         fmt.Println(conn, "IP end")
   }
      fmt.Println("End")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you're using `Scanner`'s instance for comparison here not the input. You should store the value returned by [`Text()`](https://golang.org/pkg/bufio/#Scanner.Text) in a variable and use it for comparison.

```
typeofoperation_input := typeofoperation.Text()
add_input := addr.Text()

if typeofoperation_input == "tcp" {
}
```